# Resizing an image has distorted it unrecognisable

Tags: python, numpy

I run the following code to change the color and size of a cat image. However, the resized image distorted to something unrecognisable, like a piece of carpet. Could anyone please tell me what went wrong? Thanks!

```
import imageio

img = imageio.imread('D:/cat.jpg')                 
img_tinted = img * [1, 0.95, 0.9]               
img_tinted = np.resize(img_tinted, (300, 300, 3))  
img_tinted = img_tinted.astype(np.uint8)
imageio.imwrite('D:/cat_tinted.jpg', img_tinted)
```

[image: Distorted cat image]

Comment: maybe what you are doing is wrong,

Comment: What did I do wrong?

Comment: which python version you are using, does this executes fine `img_tinted = img * [1, 0.95, 0.9]`?

Comment: I hate to be scold, but did you read the docs for `np.resize`?  You must have to pass working parameters, but did you pay attention to how it filled in the new values?  Look in `imageio` or other image packages for `resizing` methods.

Comment: @hpaulj, I think you're right. The original code used ```img_tinted = imresize(img_tinted, (300, 300))``` but I got a warning of deprecate or something so I tried to be "creative". Do you happen to know an applicable resize function?